# error 1064 when running query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm adding an address data to my query.

```html
$insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `order` 
(BuyerName,BuyerEmail,BuyerAddress,TransactionID,DateTime,ItemAmount,)
VALUES ('$buyerName','$buyerEmail','$BuyerAddress','$transactionID','$date',
'$ItemTotalPrice')");
```

before adding the `$BuyerAddress` it works just fine. but after i change the query i get

> Error : (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
>                       VALUES ('Amin black','testcart2@gmail.com','Level 01, No 1, First Avenue' at line 2

this is how i get address data

```
    $BuyerAddress = urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["SHIPTOSTREET"])
.' '.urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["SHIPTOCITY"])                                     
.' '.urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["SHIPTOSTATE"])
.' '.urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["SHIPTOZIP"])
.' '.urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME"]);
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with it?
or am i combining the address the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove comma after `ItemAmount` in you query-field-list

```
$insert_row = $mysqli->query("
    INSERT INTO `order` 
        (BuyerName, BuyerEmail, BuyerAddress, TransactionID, DateTime, ItemAmount)
    VALUES 
        ('$buyerName', '$buyerEmail', '$BuyerAddress', '$transactionID', '$date', '$ItemTotalPrice')
");
```

Comment: how a simple mistake could ruin it all.

Comment: its silly mistake. cos error message tells you where is actual error. simple mistake for example (php) is to put `=` when u need `==` or `==` when need `===` in `if` expression